# replace collection in bidirectional one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Given the following JPA entities that have a bidirectional one-to-many relationship

```
@Entity
public class Cart {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cart")
    private Set<Items> items;
    
    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Items {
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cart_id", nullable=false)
    private Cart cart;
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

If I load a cart from the database that already contains some items

```
Cart cartWithItems = CartRepository.findById(cartId);
```

And I want to replace the items in this cart with a new collection of items

```
Set<Item> newCartItems = ItemRepository.findAllById(newItemIds);
```

What is the simplest/best way to perform this replacement? Ideally, I would like the generated SQL statements to be reasonably efficient, but my main goal is perform the replacement using code that's concise and readable.

### Update

Just to be clear about what I mean by replacement:

If the cart initially contains items with IDs 2, 3, 4 and `newItemIds` contains 4, 5, 6, then after the replacement, the cart should contain items with IDs 4, 5, 6, and items with IDs 2, 3 should continue to exist (i.e. they should not be deleted).

Comment: What do you want to happen with Item with ID=2 and 3 in the given scenario? Can  they exist independently from the cart when dereferenced ( could they be transferred to other carts even), or should they be deleted?

Comment: @Chris see the Update section above

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend adding `orphanRemoval = true` to your `OneToMany` annotation and then just remove the items from your cart. Furthermore I would recommend an `add` method that handles the bidirectional part like this:

```java
public void addItem(Item item) {
  if(item != null) {
    this.items.add(item);
    item.setCart(this);
  }
}
```

You could also add a `remove` function if you wanted to.
The `addItem` function could be used like this:

```java
cartWithItems.setItems(new HashSet<>());
newCartItems.forEach(cartWithItems::addItem);
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would it be possible for you to add the code that performs the removal of the items?

Comment: `orphanRemoval = true` + `cartWithItems.setItems(new HashSet<>());` should remove the items on save